# Cloud SQL minor patch upgrade not working for MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

As per [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/release-notes#May_26_2022) I should be able to upgrade the minor patch of the database, which by default is `8.0.26` in newly fresh instances:

> **May 26, 2022**
>
> Cloud SQL for MySQL now supports minor version 8.0.29. To upgrade your existing instance to the new version, see [Upgrade the database minor version](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-minor-db-version).

I triggered a minor patch upgrade using GCP CLI for MySQL. The command output is successful but the database patch didn't change. Used the following command:

```bash
$ gcloud sql instances patch mysqldb
The following message will be used for the patch API method.
{"name": "mysqldb", "project": "myproject", "settings": {}}
Patching Cloud SQL instance...done.     
Updated [https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/myproject/instances/mysqldb].
```

It didn't upgrade, so I restarted the MySQL instance, and even after that the version remained `8.0.26`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected because when you execute `gcloud sql instances patch mysqldb` this will do nothing about an upgrade because actually you're not setting what to patch.

If you look at the body sent to the API it is almost "empty"

```json
{"name": "mysqldb", "project": "myproject", "settings": {}}
```

Moreover, in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-minor-db-version) you link it mentions that to upgrade the instance you should specify the new version.

```bash
gcloud sql instances patch mysqldb --database-version=MYSQL_8_0_29
```

which results in

```json
{"databaseVersion": "MYSQL_8_0_29", "name": "mysqldb", "project": "myproject", "settings": {}}
```

[image]

Comment: I checked the cli page for versions but didn't check the extended versions list, it works.

Comment: But what is the difference between `--database-version` and `--maintenance-version`?

Comment: Also, list of values of the MySQL versions https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/SqlDatabaseVersion